# Do I need to unsubscribe from events of a WebClient if I dispose of my Webclient

Tags: c#, events, webclient, idisposable

So Ive got my WebClient wrapped in a using statement. But I suddenly wondered do I need to unsubscribe from events if my object implements IDisposable and is wrapped in a using statment?

Below is my example code of how I am currently using my `WebClient`. Will this code currently have memory leaks as it is not unsubscribing from events or will the dispose method deal with that?

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += ((sender, args) =>
    {
       //monitor something
    });
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += ((sender, args) =>
    {
       //do something
    });
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", Settings1.Default.WebPhotosLocation, Path.GetFileName(f.FullName))), filePath);
}
```

Comment: You ought to dispose it manually.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Could you please expand on your comment? what does `it` relate to? my `WebClient` will be disposed through the using statement surely? as for event handlers I cannot dispose of those

Comment: You're disposing the WebClient before the async operation is completed(DownloadFileAsync), I'm not sure that is legal to do. and also your event handlers will not be removed on `Dispose` if your event handler points to some instance method, then the instance will not be GC'd till the web client is GC'd.

Comment: Ok so in my real example I use a manual reset to make sure the `WebClient` isnt disposed of before the file is downloaded. Does an anonymous method count as an instance method? I would have thought that calling `Dispose` would cause the `WebClient` to be garbage collected

Comment: @user1 if you use an event to wait until the async actions are complete, then what's the point of using async IO in the first place? Also Dispose does not interact with GC. It simply eagerly releases resources.

Comment: @usr Because downloading a file snchronously blocks the UI meaning you cannot update the user on a downloads progress. hence you must download the file asynchronously with a manual reset to make sure it downloads one at a time meanwhile it is also able to update the UI on its progress

Comment: When you use an event you block the UI thread as well. It's about blocking the UI thread, not about using async IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no need.  Once the WebClient is collected by the GC all of the event handlers will be cleaned up for you.  Before GC occurs they'll do no harm as it won't be possible for the events to fire so the handlers will never be called.